# Unhandled exception Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD - in Structure C++

Tags: c++

I created a structure pointer. And Assign values to it. I tried to print the values assigned to it. It complains Unhandled exception Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD. What's wrong with doing like this? How to achieve this task without exception?

```
StructCol.h

#include "stdafx.h"
#ifndef StructCol_H
#define StructCol_H

#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct ABC
{
    string test;
    int no;

    void print()
    {
        cout << test << endl;
        cout << no << endl;
    }
};

#endif

StructTest2.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "StructCol.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ABC*abc = (ABC*)malloc(sizeof(ABC));
    abc->no = 47;
    abc->test = "fyp";
    abc->print();
    //delete abc;
    //abc->print();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your structure contains a `std::string` element. That is a type that needs its **constructor** to be executed when that object is created.

You cannot create your struct with `malloc` because that C function doesn't know about constructors.

The C++ `new` and `delete` expressions will do the correct thing. Of course, you should really prefer using smart pointers instead of manual memory management (or no dynamic allocation at all).

The quick way to fix your code is to use `new` and `delete`:

```
ABC *abc = new ABC;
...
delete abc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use malloc,  use new ou std::unique_ptr. Malloc dont call ABC constructor so the string constructor isnt called too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `free()` instead of `delete` to release the memory pointed to by `abc`.

The `delete` operator should only be used in conjunction with the `new` operator.

Second, you are getting this error most probably because of the second print statement after using `delete`.

After you release the memory of a location you should not access it in any way because the OS may reclaim it and you may no longer have access to it. The **access violation error** is the indication of the security provided by the OS to prevent access to a memory by an unauthorized process.